# Sorting Restkit objects in ascending order

Tags: ios, objective-c, sorting, restkit

Can you help me.Actually i'm using restkit in my project,i have done  all my works in this project except this.In here,have to shortlist several restkit objects with key param(class object) as activity_created.pls find my code in below screenshot and give me the better solution.[image]

this code just reverse my list.

Comment: What is the type of RBActivity activity_created? You may need to make sure the activity_created is comparable first

Comment: i'm not sure about this comparable or not..in that RBActivity i map json responce objects..

Comment: So it sorts, but the opposite order to what you want?

Comment: i'm having lots of data(messages),i need to sort these thing by date&time

Comment: show the definition of `RBActivity`, also show some sample data and how it's currently sorting.

Comment: thanks Wain and user3349433....i found soulution for my question.. and posted my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to answer me Guys.i found solution for my question,as follows[image]

and this is working fine..

Comment: Please replace the image with text. The image cannot be indexed for searching. And people can copy and paste the code into their own project. And please do the same in the question.